# How To Show Data as Option of Different DB Table

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vuejs2, laravel-5.7

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*`.I am building an invoice application.

I have a table of `Vendors` and need to show all `Vendors` in my **create Invoice** form (e.g This invoice is related to the selected `Vendor`).

This is my `<script>` code:

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        ticketInvoices: {},
        ticketInvoiceItems: [],
        form: new Form({
          id: "",
          vendor_id: "",
          ticket_invoice_no: "",
          ticket_invoice_date: "",
          ticket_invoice_grand_total: "",
        })
      };
    },
    methods: {
      addItems() {
        this.ticketInvoiceItems.push({
          id: "",
          passenger_name: "",
          ticket_no: "",
          flight_no: "",
          departure_date: "",
          sub_total: ""
        });
      },
      removeItems(pos) {
        this.ticketInvoiceItems.splice(pos, 1);
      },
      </script>
```

Need to show `Vendor` list here:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="vendor">Select Vendor</label>
  <select class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('vendor') }">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select Vendor</option>
    <option>All Vendors Name</option>
  </select>
  <has-error :form="form" field="vendor"></has-error>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a controller that returns data of all vendors. Something like;

```
public function index()
{
   $vendors = Vendor::all();
   return $vendors;
}
```

This returns a JSON response with all vendors.

In your html code, you can do this;

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="vendor">Select Vendor</label>
    <select class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('vendor')}">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select Vendor</option>
        <option v-for="vendor in vendors">{{ vendor }}</option>
    </select>
    <has-error :form="form" field="vendor"></has-error>
</div>
```

In your Vue code;

```
data () {
    return {
      vendors: null
    }
},
mounted () {
axios
  .get('https://example.com/api/vendors')
  .then(response => (this.vendors = response))
}
```

Comment: Is their any need to `v-model` in my `<select>` for sending data to my `DB` with `Vendor ID` @PeterSowah ...??? And yeah i can see all my `vendors` list in my `Invoice` form. Thanks.

Comment: If my post/answer is helped in anyway please mark it as the answer. And yeah, you could create an object off the form inputs. You'll use `v-model` in this case.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mark it :P BTW Thank You @PeterSowah